# get 2 arrays from core data separate them by nsdate

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdate, nssortdescriptor

ok this one should be easy.  For creating a app in Xcode.   I have one View.  This view has two table views. upcomingEventsTableView and expiredEventsTableView.   I am pulling data for core data.   This data has names "event" and nsDate "eventTimeStart".   I want the eventTimeStart NSDate data split from the current time "nowDate".  I want to display the past data on the expiredEventsTableView and the NSDates in the future to show up on the upcomingEventsTableView.   I think I'm on the right track but having troubles around my sort descriptors area.  So far I have the same dates on both tableviews.  Just don't know how to separate the dates for each tableview.

```
@interface EventsViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;


@end

@implementation EventsViewController

@synthesize upcomingEventsTableView;
@synthesize expiredEventsTableView;


-(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext{
return [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]managedObjectContext];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[self.upcomingEventsTableView reloadData];
[self.expiredEventsTableView reloadData];

//scrollview stuff
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
[self.scrollView layoutIfNeeded];
self.scrollView.contentSize=self.contentView.bounds.size;

NSError *error = nil;

if(![[self fetchedResultsController]performFetch:&error]){
    NSLog(@"Error! %@", error);
    abort();
}

}

//upcoming & EXPIRED events tableview
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self.upcomingEventsTableView reloadData];
[self.expiredEventsTableView reloadData];
}
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
if (upcomingEventsTableView){
return 1;
} else {
return 1;
}
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

// Return the number of rows in the section.

if (upcomingEventsTableView){

id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo =  [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];

return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}else{
id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo =   [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];

return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}



//format the date
-(NSDate *)convertDateToDate:(NSDate *) date
{
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *nowDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-d H:m:s"];
NSString * strdate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
nowDate = [formatter dateFromString:strdate];
return nowDate;
}



#pragma mark - fetched results controller section

-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController {
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil){
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"eventTimeStart" ascending:YES];


NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

if ([sortDescriptors earlierDate: nowDate] == sortDescriptors) {
    NSLog(@"upcoming");
    //create nsarray upcoming here and apply to tableview  upcomingEventsTableView;
}else{
    NSLog(@"expired");
    //create nsarray upcoming here and apply to tableview  expiredEventsTableView
}

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;
}

#pragma Mark - fetched results controller delegates

-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
[self.upcomingEventsTableView beginUpdates];
}

-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
[self.upcomingEventsTableView endUpdates];
}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

UITableView *tableView = self.upcomingEventsTableView; //creating a temporary placeholder;

switch (type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:newIndexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:{
        Event *changeEvent = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = changeEvent.eventName;
        break;
    }
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

}

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to 2 table views is 2 sections in one table view.  This will not work if you want each set of data to be split into sections, but in the code you posted, you don't seem to be doing that.

You create one FRC for each section, and for whichever FRC represents section 1 (second section), you have to adjust indexPaths when moving between the FRC and the table view.  It's not all that difficult to manage.

Comment: I actually am going a diffrent direction with this.   Since all answers wanted to split things up.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if (upcomingEventsTableView){
```

will always return true, because you're just testing a pointer exists, not what it actually points to. So your delegate method is always returning the same items to both tables. The code in each option is the same at the moment anyway, but still...

You should really separate your concerns and have 2 view controllers, 1 for each table view.

You can do this using a single class that you instantiate twice and provide each with a predicate. That predicate allows the class to find the subset of data it should display, and in this case it's based on the date. The first one gets a predicate `< nowDate` and the second `>= nowDate`.

Each now has their own FRC instance which will return the correct items for it to display and everything is nicely compartmentalised and reusable.

Comment: Am i doing it in the correct place?        if ([sortDescriptors earlierDate: nowDate] == sortDescriptors) {
    NSLog(@"upcoming");
    //create nsarray upcoming here and apply to tableview  upcomingEventsTableView;
}else{
    NSLog(@"expired");
    //create nsarray upcoming here and apply to tableview   expiredEventsTableView
    }

Comment: You don't split the data with a sort, you split it with a predicate.

Comment: and do i want to use something like - (NSDate *)earlierDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate

Comment: Use an `NSPredicate` on the fetch - I've reworded the answer a bit, do you understand the reusability and have you used predicates before ?

Comment: could i use nspredicate to create two arrays, and separate them to past and future?

Comment: yes, but you should really have 2 FRCs with different predicates than do 1 fetch and then split the result array in 2 with a predicate